# Save image from image URL on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, url

I used jQuery to paste an image from clipboard on web form.  **How Can I save that particular image on server in a specific folder?**

I can manage to save pasted image URL in hidden field and I am getting the image URL in code behind. Here is what I have.

> blob:http%3A//localhost%3A58279/23b47755-bd44-44d0-9ca5-4177d7cc1dd3

Here is you can go, and try pasting image from clipboard. [Link](http://patientregistration.azurewebsites.net/default2.aspx)

Comment: "I used jQuery to paste an image from clipboard on web form."  By web form, do you mean the server side ASP.NET technology, or the HTML <form> element?  Neither really makes sense.  Are you pasting to an HTML5 canvas, or a Flash plugin, or something else?

Comment: Check this http://patientregistration.azurewebsites.net/default2.aspx

Comment: You can paste an image from clipboard on page. just try.

Answer (score 2):

**Server side:**

```
Request.Files["field name"].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/directory/file.name"));
```

**Client side - ECMAScript:**

```
var dropTarget = document.getElementById('dropTarget');
dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', makeDrop, false);

function makeDrop(event) {
    var filelist = event.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!filelist) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
        var file = filelist[i];
        uploadFile(file);
    }
}

function uploadFile(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/api.ashx', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status == 200) { 
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

**Client side - HTML:**

```
<div id="dropTarget"></div>
```

Comment: you did not read the question properly. There is no file in request.Files...

Comment: then don't use jQuery when it is not working and use pure JS+HTML instead